# Can I see a log-file of startup applications?

Tags: log, startup-applications

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.
I added some applications in start applications program. Is there any log of them as if they had started in the terminal?

E.g.: I added `deluge` to the startup apps, but I'm not sure it's working well. I would like to check in some way whether it's working.

Comment: Sure, in mutiple ways. Is it only about apps in Startup Applications? Could you explain a bit on *why*? It would make it easier to answer the question adequately.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: *sudo* -anything will not work as a startup command for sure, unless you edited the sudoers file...

Comment: Ok, I understood. I changed my example!

Comment: There is a mismatch between the title question and the body question leading to the non-answer by Jacob Vlijm.  Please choose one question.

Comment: I changed slightly the title. I hope this could help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if the startup app is a script, you could add as the last line of the script,

logger "such-n-such script started."

Then, it will appear in /var/log/syslog

Comment: But what if it isn't a script?